# continuous extension of Banach space-valued analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, analyticity

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $U\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ be a bounded open subset of the complex plane.  Suppose that $f:U\to X$ is an analytic function.

It is well-known that $f$ may not admit a continuous extension to the closure $\overline{U}$.  However, in the situation I am working, I only need this:

**Conjecture.**  There is a finite set $A\subset\mathbb{C}$ so that $f$ admits a continuous extension to $\overline{U}\setminus A$.

Is this conjecture true?  If not, are there some modest assumptions we could impose on $U$ to make it true?

Thank you!

Comment: from $U$ open you can embed it into $V$ simply connected that is embedable (with a biholomorphic map) to the unit disk $D$, so you can restrict to the case $U = D$, and the answer is no, since from $f(z)$ bounded with finitely many discontinuities  on $|z| = 1$ you get $g(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty f(z e^{i/k}) e^{-k}$ analytic and having  infinitely many discontinuities on $|z|=1$

Comment: I think i agree with the comment above in that if you assume $U$ is holomorphic to the disk, then i think the result holds. To prove it, choose any linear functional, say $\lambda : X\to \mathbb{C}$. Then $\lambda \circ f : \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{C}. I believe that if the result hold for this function and hence for any $\lambda$ you choose. Then it remains to extend the result to $f$.